# clang not recognizing inline attribute after preprocessor expansion

Tags: c, clang, c-preprocessor

So my header looks like this:

```
#include "compiler.h"

INLINE FUNC(boolean, DIAG_APPL_CODE) Cdd_IsXcpActive(void){
   return (boolean)(Cdd_Dcm_NvM_Coding_Adaption_Block[CODING_ADAPTION_XCP_ACTIVATION_OFFSET] == 1);
}
```

In compiler.h

```
#define INLINE inline
#define FUNC(x, y) x
typedef unsigned char boolean;
```

is defined

When trying to compile I get with -E

```
inline boolean Cdd_IsXcpActive(void){
  return (boolean)(Cdd_Dcm_NvM_Coding_Adaption_Block[0 +1U] == 1);
}
```

Which indicates that everything is being preprocessed correctly.

Still clang complains:

```
clang --analyze -Weverything -Wextra -std=c89 -c -g3 -O -D_lint -I . -I AID -I CDD -I COM -I config -I DIA -I MC -I MCAL -I OS -I RTE CDD/Cdd_Diag.c -o CDD/bin_ninja/Cdd_Diag.o

In file included from CDD/Cdd_Diag.c:5:
CDD/Cdd_Diag.h:32:1: error: unknown type name 'inline'
INLINE FUNC(boolean, DIAG_APPL_CODE) Cdd_IsXcpActive(void){
^
AID/Compiler.h:233:17: note: expanded from macro 'INLINE'
        #define INLINE  inline
                        ^
In file included from CDD/Cdd_Diag.c:5:
CDD/Cdd_Diag.h:32:37: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
INLINE FUNC(boolean, DIAG_APPL_CODE) Cdd_IsXcpActive(void){
                                    ^
                                    ;
```

clang version

```
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
Target: i386-pc-cygwin
Thread model: posix
```

Does anybody know what might be going on here?

Comment: it’s `bool` not `boolean`

Comment: @bolov c89 does not know either. There is a typedef for the type in `compiler.h`.

Comment: Methinks `inline` was not added before C99. What happens if you compile with `-std=c99`?

Comment: @RedX there you go. C89 doesn’t have inline.

Comment: @bolov: Compilers were smarter back then, and could figure out what to inline and what not to inline better than people can. ;-)

Comment: `-std=gnu89` seems to work, in case this is an option for you.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yep that is the cause. The solution is to use gnu89 as proposed by mafso.

Comment: @mafso If you post an answer i will mark it as correct.

Comment: As a side note, please try to straighten your question before posting. Here obviously this has nothing to do with macro expansion.

Comment: @JensGustedt You are right and i felt very dumb when it was clear that it was just a matter of the standard i chose. I will next time investigate the cause better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `inline` keyword was added in C99, so Clang treats it as a type name with `-std=c89`.

You can use the `-std=gnu89` flag instead of `-std=c89`, which supports `inline`. Note, however, that it is implemented with slightly different semantics. From [the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#extensions-supported-by-clang):

> The `*99` modes default to implementing `inline` as specified in C99, while the `*89` modes implement the GNU version. This can be overridden for individual functions with the `__gnu_inline__` attribute.

From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes):

> - `gnu_inline`
>
> This attribute should be used with a function that is also declared with the `inline` keyword. It directs GCC to treat the function as if it were defined in `gnu90` mode even when compiling in C99 or `gnu99` mode.
>   If the function is declared `extern`, then this definition of the function is used only for inlining. In no case is the function compiled as a standalone function, not even if you take its address explicitly. Such an address becomes an external reference, as if you had only declared the function, and had not defined it. This has almost the effect of a macro. The way to use this is to put a function definition in a header file with this attribute, and put another copy of the function, without `extern`, in a library file. The definition in the header file causes most calls to the function to be inlined. If any uses of the function remain, they refer to the single copy in the library. Note that the two definitions of the functions need not be precisely the same, although if they do not have the same effect your program may behave oddly.
>
> In C, if the function is neither `extern` nor `static`, then the function is compiled as a standalone function, as well as being inlined where possible.
>
> This is how GCC traditionally handled functions declared `inline`. Since ISO C99 specifies a different semantics for `inline`, this function attribute is provided as a transition measure and as a useful feature in its own right. This attribute is available in GCC 4.1.3 and later. It is available if either of the preprocessor macros `__GNUC_GNU_INLINE__` or `__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__` are defined. See [An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html#Inline).